# How do i know if the ADODB is connected to my database using vb.net (class, module and form)

Tags: vb.net, mariadb

I hope the title is enough to understand my problem, it already installed whats need to run the ADODBC, my problem is how do i know if the connection is connected to the database mariadb

```
Module GlobalVariables
    Public sGlobalConnectionString As String

    Sub Main()
        Dim clsFunction As New clsFunction
        Dim sParameter As String
        Dim sDataserver As String
        Dim sDatabaseName As String
        Dim sDatabaseConnection As String

        sDataserver = "localhost"
        sDatabaseName = "employee"
        sDatabaseConnection = "Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver}; SERVER=" & sDataserver & "; UID=root;PWD=*****; Database=" & sDatabaseName & "; PORT=3307; OPTION=3"
        sGlobalConnectionString = sDatabaseConnection
    End Sub
End Module
```

this is my class

```
Public Class Query
    Private Sub Class_ConOpen()
        Dim con = New ADODB.Connection
        con.ConnectionString = sGlobalConnectionString
        con.Open
        con.CommandTimeout = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub Class_ConClose()
        Dim con = New ADODB.Connection
        If Not con Is Nothing Then
            con.Close
            con = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

this is my form, is this right? going to used try catch?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
           ?????
        Catch ex As Exception
           ????
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using ADODB in VB.NET to begin with? Generally speaking, you should be using ADO.NET for data access in VB.NET. You just connect when you need to connect and close the connection immediately afterwards.

Comment: because that was may instructor requirement

Comment: i dont have a choice but to follow

Comment: It is a disgrace that anyone gets paid for teaching decades-old, obsolete technology. Ya gotta do what ya gotta do though.

Comment: but im a stident though, its hard to learn when the class is online, i mean online teaching

Comment: That last comment was not a criticism of you. It was a criticism of whomever is teaching you for not learning the language and technology well enough to teach it properly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney good day, i updated my question , please help sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228249/discussion-between-rene-and-jmcilhinney).

Comment: Why did you change original question? Now, the answers are NOT related to the actual question! I'd suggest to reject changes and ask another question related to your actual issue. Your original question was about how to check if app is connected to the database...

Comment: Okay okay, mybad

Comment: @MaciejLos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043400/how-do-i-get-the-data-to-my-database-using-vb-net-class-module-and-form heres the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to find out if your application is connected to the database is to execute command, such as `SELECT servername;`.
Even if the state of connection is `Open` there's no 100% that you're connected to the database. In other word, if command will execute without errors, connection is OK.

Comment: how about in form?, example when i click button, messagebox will appear if the application is connected in the database

Comment: is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to inform user about current connection status.

Comment: As @jmcilhinney mentioned, you should rather use ADO.NET. Please, follow the documentation: [MySqlConnector for ADO.NET](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlconnector-for-adonet/). There you'll find sample code.

Comment: sorry but i cant do that, the requirement is ADODB

Comment: Well... Please, visit this site: [Easy ADODB Recordsets and Commands in Access](https://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/01/21/easy-adodb-recordsets-and-commands-in-access/). There's no matter of database provider. The code is the same. Note, that you should use existing connection. So, do not create another one, but use yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228248/discussion-between-rene-and-maciej-los).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the State property of con object.

`con.State` property will tell you the state of the connection.

Comment: Nope. Please, see my answer.

Comment: @MaciejLos Yup, a connection string for Access has a DataSource attribute. So, if the connection state is Open then the connection is connected to the database.

Comment: @Mary, sorry, but you're wrong. Please, see my answer.

Comment: @MaciejLos I did see your answer.  Since the connection string contains the the database file name and your code does not refer to the database name any further it seems to be when you connect, you connect to the database. There is no "server" in Access so, what would you be connecting to if not the database?

Comment: @Mary, take a look at conection string provided by OP. He tries to connect to MaraDB database, not to MS Access database.

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes, and there is a Database= attribute! If that database doesn't exist or the permissions are not satisfied the connection will fail. The code will not for the command will not include `Use MyDatabase` since the connection is to the particular database.