# How to connect my vb.net Project to mariadb using ADO.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I had this module that handled the connection string that connect to my database:

```
Module DBCONNECTION
    Public myGlobalConnectionString As String
    Public Sub Main()

        Dim sDataserver As String
        Dim sDatabaseName As String
        Dim sDatabaseConnection As String
        Try
           sDataserver = "localhost"
           sDatabaseName = "Student"

           sDatabaseConnection  = ("Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};SERVER=" & sDataserver & ";USER=root;PASSWORD=****;DATABASE=" & sDatabaseName & ";PORT=3306")
           sDatabaseConnection = myGlobalConnectionString 
       Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
  End Sub
End Module
```

and i had this class that will open and close the connection of `myGlobalConnectionString`

```
Public Shared Sub OpenDb()
    Dim con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = myGlobalConnectionString
    con.Open() // when it tried to open, the error appear
End Sub
Public Shared Sub CloseDb()
    Dim con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    If Not con Is Nothing Then
        con.Close()
        con = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

and my form

```
Private Sub LoginForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim con As New clsDataQuery
    con.OpenDb()
End Sub
```

I get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Think you've got this lin in your main sub wrong. sDatabaseConnection = myGlobalConnectionString should be myGlobalConnectionString = sDatabaseConnection shouldn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i get the data to my database using vb.net (class, module and form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043400/how-do-i-get-the-data-to-my-database-using-vb-net-class-module-and-form)

Comment: Just don't do this. Connections should be created in the method where they are used. Not just opened and left flapping in the breeze. They need to be creating in a `Using...End Using` block where they are properly disposed.